# Как сделать такой layout?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используя `flexbox`, `display: inline-block`, блоки выглядели вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.container {
  columns: 4;
  column-gap: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.item {
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}

.item:nth-of-type(1),
.item:nth-of-type(4),
.item:nth-of-type(9) {
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```